# How to access data loaded with gatsby-source-graphql in a resolver?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

In Gatsby how can I create a resolver that uses data loaded by the gatsby-source-graphql plugin. I'm having trouble figuring out to query the data inside a resolver. Can this be done? Any advice on what I'm missing would be helpful.

something like this in gatsby-node.js ...

```
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  createResolvers({
    Query: {
      getStructure: {
        type: `Structure`,
        async resolve(source, args, context, info) {

          // assume gatsby-config.js is configured with gatsby-source-graphql and this node exists
          const myGraphQlApiNode = await context.nodeModel.runQuery({
            query: {
              filter: {
                fieldName: { eq: "myGqlApi" }
              }
            },
            type: "GraphQLSource"
          });

          const someGqlApiData = // query all of type MyGqlApi_SomeTypeFromGqlApi loaded via gatsby-source-graphql

          return toStructure(someGqlApiData)
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be an unofficial solution
Because gatsby doesn’t provide graphql method in createResolvers but do it on createPages

you can do st like this

*in gatsby-node.js*

```
let apiHelperGraphql = null

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql }) => {
// steal it from create Pages
  apiHelperGraphql = graphql
}
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
// and call it here, do what ever you want
apiHelperGraphql(`same as grapql syntax`)
}
```